# Script in /etc/rc3.d not start on boot

Tags: boot, scripts

I have a problem with a script that have run on boot.
I put this easy script in /etc/init.d

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          start_app
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:   2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:    0 1
# Short-Description: Start service
# Description: Start and Stop service
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in start)
        su - ats -c start.sh
        ;; stop)
        su - ats -c stop.sh
        ;;   *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;; esac

:
```

I linked this script on /etc/rc3.d

```
ln -s ../init.d/start_app S40start_app
```

Both script and link have the correct permission

```
root@euromobappts:/etc/rc3.d# ll S40start_app
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Aug  6 14:43 S40start_app -> ../init.d/start_app*
root@euromobappts:/etc/rc3.d# ll ../init.d/start_app
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 412 Aug  7 08:08 ../init.d/start_app*
```

But this not run on boot.
I have another script but this second run correctly; the different is that this contain a `su - user -c command`.
I tried to change in `sudo su - user -c command` without any change.

Any idea?

Many thanks

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Canonical Ubuntu 16.04 
many Thanks